# Tag system variant

Tags: reference-request, computation-models

Is there an "official" name for this slight variant of the well known [Tag System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_system) model of computation, and/or has it been used somewhere?

- a finite alphabet of symbols $\Sigma$
- a halt symbol $H$
- an ordered set of production rules: 
  $$P_i: \alpha_i \rightarrow \beta_i, \quad \alpha_i \in \Sigma^+, \beta_i \in \Sigma^* \cup \{H\}$$
- the input $w$ is a string in $\Sigma^+$

The computation is:

1. find the first production rule $P_i$ for which $w = \alpha_i v$;
2. replace $w = \alpha_i v$ with $v\beta_i$ (i.e. delete the prefix $\alpha_i$ and append $\beta_i$)
3. halt when no production is found or $\beta_i = H$

This model differs from a tag system because 1) $\alpha_i$ is a string and not a single symbol, 2) the number of characters deleted from the prefix is not fixed.

It can easily simulate a $m$-tag system in "real-time" (for every rule $x \rightarrow P(x)$ of the m-tag system add production rules $xv \rightarrow P(x)$, $v \in |\Sigma|^{m-1}$) and therefore it can efficiently simulate a Turing machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [Post canonical system in normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system#Normal-form_theorem), tweaked slightly to incorporate a halt symbol, and to require application of only the first applicable production rule.

Comment: ok, I think that it casn be considered a *monogenic* Post Canonical system in normal form (plus the halt symbol)